# Angular to check a particular checkbox automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with a few checkboxes and form is being processed via angularjs. I have no knowledge about angular however I read about it to find a solution to my problem. I want a checkbox to be checked automatically when form is load. When I look at the codes below I don't understand anything so I need your help.

**HTML: (I think this dynamically generates a few < li > options in the form GUI)**

```
<ul class="sublist" style="padding-top:{{ $index * 38}}px;" ng-init="index=$index" ng-if="forActive == k" ng-repeat="(k, v) in forData">
    <li class="selected" ng-repeat="val in v">
        <a href="" title="">{{ val }} </a>
            <input value="{{ k }} > {{ val }}" type="checkbox" class="flc" ng-click="addForValue(k + ' > ' + val)" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Content of array is this in angular:** `$scope.design.fors = [Adults > Men,Adults > Plus]`

For example, When form is load, checkbox with **value = Adults > Men** shall be checked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is by making my object a little more rich:

```
$scope.design.fors = [ 
    { value: "Adults > Men", checked: true},
    { value: "Adults > Plus", checked: false}]
```

Then in the view you can write something like:

```
<ul class="sublist">
    <li class="selected" ng-repeat="item in design.fors">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" /> {{item.value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've changed the code to make it look like yours to solve the problem. Thanks